# Transfer a file from remote server to remote server

Tags: ssh, ftp, scp, filezilla

I am trying to transfer a file from Site5 to Godaddy web hosting account. The godaddy webhosting account is the one that comes free with the domain, so no ssh acccess.

> sudo scp -v @:/home//wordpress.tar  -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking no' @www.domain.com:/home/content/m/c/o//wordpress.tar

The destination is a godaddy free hosting acccount, and the username on it is the ftp user name.

I am getting the following error when I try to enter the password of the godaddy ftpuser

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
mconsys@www.mcruiseon.com's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
Permission denied, please try again.
mconsys@www.mcruiseon.com's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
Permission denied, please try again.
mconsys@www.mcruiseon.com's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
lost connection
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Edit (some more to help debug the issue)

When I try using FTPZilla, with FTP port it connects to the server fine. As soon as I put port 22, it accepts the RSA thingy and gives a error.

```
Response:   fzSftp started
Command:    open "mconsys@www.mcruiseon.com" 22
Command:    Trust new Hostkey: Once
Command:    Pass: ************
Error:  Authentication failed.
Error:  Critical error
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Edit 2

Ftp from the ssh enabled site5 server, gives the following error

```
ftp  mconsys@www.mcruiseon.com
ftp: mconsys@www.mcruiseon.com: unknown host
```

Comment: `scp` uses `sftp` which is (for all intents and purposes) `ssh`. If you don't have `ssh` access, this probably won't work and you'll need FTP (or other)

Comment: Cant I get scp to force a ftp login ? Sorry, silly question.

Comment: OR cant I ftp into that server ?

Comment: The FTP error is something specific to you - there is an FTP server there when I run `telnet www.mcruiseon.com 21`

Comment: Actually, do you have some sort of DNS override in `/etc/hosts`? It looks like you might be sending requests for `www.mcruiseon.com` to localhost (which would explain the authentication and lack of ftp servers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sftp` and `ftp` are *completely* different protocols so, if as you say you don't have ssh/sftp access at one end, I don't think there's any value in persuing a scp option.

I would personally ssh into the end you do have access at and then use whatever protocol you have access to to push (or pull) the files across. In you were using `ftp`:

```
user@home$ ssh user@server.com
user@server$ ftp server2.com
> # login here
> cd /the/right/path
> mget * 
> mput *
> bye
```

You don't want *both* `mget` or `mput`, just pick the one that suits the direction you're pushing or pulling files.

Comment: Thanks, your answer gave me the hint. I was adding ftp user@server, while I should have just ftp server. Thanks.